# Installation of Zbar failed

Tags: camera, video, raspicam, image

I'm trying to install Zbar but I am having an issue with `./configure`:

```
checking linux/videodev.h usability... no
checking linux/videodev.h presence... no
checking for linux/videodev.h... no
configure: error: in `/home/pi/zbar':
configure: error: test for video support failed!
rebuild your kernel to include video4linux support or
configure --disable-video to skip building video support.
```

This is what I've done so far:

```
# Get the latest Raspbian packages

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

## JPEG DEPENDENCIES    
### download and compile the JPEG library

wget http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz    
tar xvfz jpegsrc.v8c.tar.gz
cd jpeg-8c
./configure --enable-shared --prefix=$CONFIGURE_PREFIX
make
sudo make install

### link the libraries correctly - RASPBERRY PI ONLY

sudo ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libjpeg.so /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libfreetype.so /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libz.so /usr/lib

### install rest of the libraries, as well as freetrype and zlib

sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev

### re-install PIL
sudo pip install pillow

## V4L UTILS
# Get the source code for the V4L utilities

git clone git://git.linuxtv.org/v4l-utils.git
cd v4l-utils

# Install some packages needed to build it
sudo apt-get install autoconf gettext libtool

# Configure and build it.
./bootstrap.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install

# Load the module video0
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

I have downloaded the latest Zbar firmware from [here](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/).

Any ideas? I want to build it with video support, so deactivating it takes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842235/linux-videodev-h-no-such-file-or-directory-opencv-on-ubuntu-11-04) :

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev
sudo ln -s /usr/include/libv4l1-videodev.h   /usr/include/linux/videodev.h
```

But I needed more dependencies (solution found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1607632)) :

```
sudo apt-get install libperl-dev
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

Then I had to install pygtk but it seems needing `python-gobject-dev` to compile :

```
sudo apt-get install python-gobject-dev
```

Downloaded the latest stable release of PyGTK [here](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/pygtk/2.24/) and installed it.

and then I tried in Zbar directory : `./configure --without-imagemagick --without-qt`

I can't find a way to install ImageMagick on my Rpi then I had to putt `--without-imagemagick` but then the prompt told me that `the zbarimg file scanner will *NOT* be built`...

Well with this I could FINALLY install it !

Maybe I'm going to use Picamera library with QRtools ...

**EDIT :**

This should work and it is EASIER to install Zbar !

```
sudo apt-get install python-qrtools
sudo apt-get install libzbar-dev
sudo pip install zbar
```

Comment: There is a Segmentation Fault error when importing qrtools in python when zbar is installed. Removing zbar resolved the problem.